# How do I prove 'For all integers a, there exists an integer b so that 3|a+b and 3|2a+b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> My approach is to divide the prove into 2 cases, where case1 is when
>   its just 'a' and case 2 is when it is '2a'.

Is that any close to being the correct proof?

Comment: You want these divisibilities to hold simultaneously?  But if $3$ divides both of these then $3$ divides $(2a+b)-(a+b)=a$.

Comment: Are you sure this is right?  Suppose a = 1.  There exists a $b$ such that 3|(1+b) and 3|(2+b)?

Comment: @00111000  But in that case my first comment holds...your claim is only true when $3 |a$ (in which case you can take $b=0$).

Comment: So you would start out by saying that 3 must divide a? and then say that b = 0.

Comment: Well.  I'd say that such a $b$ can only exist if $3$ divides $a$, and if $3$ divides $a$ then we can take $b$ to be any multiple of $3$, $0$ being a particularly simple example.

Comment: @00111000 To summarize the comments here, there is no way to prove your statement because it is false. There is a way to *dis*prove it, namely by considering a counterexample such as $a=1$ (for which you can show that no $b$ exists).

Answer (score 4):

If $a=1$ then $1+b=3M$ and $2+b=3N$. This implies $1=3(N-M)$, absurde. The statement is false.